# what does @property actually do behind the scene..with usage of self. and self-> and _ underscore

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I'm still struggling with the syntax errors in @implementation section.

So, I want to understand the difference between using @property and not.

**First case** is would be one @interface where i declared some variable in {}.

```
//ViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Student.h"       // just class i made

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    Student *stObj;
}
```

And, i'm trying to refer to stObj pointer using several identifier ( _(underscore), self. , self->, nothing)

```
//  ViewController.m


#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () // just leaving this code cuz i haven't study what it is :)

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    stObj = [[Student alloc]init ];        //no error

    //self->stObj = [[Student alloc]init];  //no error
    //self.stObj = [[Student alloc]init];   //error!
    //_stObj = [[Student alloc]init];       //error!



 }
```

---

**Second case** is would be one @interface where i use @property

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property Student *stObj;

@end
```

and do the same thing like above.

```
stObj = [[Student alloc]init ];        //error
//self->stObj = [[Student alloc]init];  //error
//self.stObj = [[Student alloc]init];   //no error!
//_stObj = [[Student alloc]init];       //no error!
```

SO, as you can see what i had to assume was that self. and _ (underscore) worked and seems similar ...?

**The Question** is that what @property actually does causing different result..?

Thank you for reading my question and if i'm doing something wrong please correct me.

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's explain what a property is: it's basically a set of methods, usually for accessing an instance variable. That's an overly simple (and slightly incorrect) explanation but it will suffice most of the time.

You can define the name of the instance variable with the `@synthesize` keyword, as in:

```
@property Type foo;

...

@synthesize foo = somethingElse;
```

In this case, the compiler will generate:

- An instance variable called `somethingElse` of type `Type`.
- A method to read the variable called `foo`: it just returns the content of the variable `somethingElse`.
- A method to write the variable called `setFoo:`: it sets the content of the variable `somethingElse` and takes care of notifying key-value observers.

If you don't specify a `@synthesize` statement, the compiler will automatically generate an instance variable with the property name prefixed by an underscore. So if your property is named `foo`, the automatically created instance variable is called `_foo`.

When you do:

```
@property Student *stObj;
```

(without a `@synthesize`) the compiler generates:

- An instance variable `_stObj` of type `Student *`.
- A method called `stObj` that reads the content of the variable `_stObj`.
- A method called `setStObj:` that writes the content of the variable `_stObj`.

Next, access to instance variables: you can either access them by their name directly, if the scope allows it (like `_foo`), or you can access them via the `->` dereference operator as in `self->_foo`. The later also allows you to access public instance variables of other objects, as in `otherObject->_foo`. Don't do this unless you *really* know what you're doing, though.

Last but not least, the dot-notation. Writing `obj.method` is the same as writing `[obj method]` and writing `obj.method = value` is the same as writing `[obj setMethod:value]`. That is, the dot-notation is a shorter syntax for a method call. (I tend to avoid it since it's also the notation for access struct members, but that's just me.)

With that knowledge, your examples are easy to explain:

In your first example:

```
stObj = [[Student alloc] init]; // Access to instance variable. OK.
self->stObj = [[Student alloc]init]; // Access to instance variable. OK

// The next statement is the same as [self setStObj:[[Student alloc]init];
// But there is no method named setStObj: defined.
self.stObj = [[Student alloc]init];
// Trying to access a variable that doesn't exist. It's called stObj instead.
_stObj = [[Student alloc]init];
```

In your second example:

```
// There is no variable stObj, it's called _stObj in this case.
stObj = [[Student alloc]init ]; // That's why this fails.
self->stObj = [[Student alloc]init]; // And this as well.

// The property has created the `setStObj:` method, so the next
// line succeeds.
self.stObj = [[Student alloc]init];
// The property has created the _stObj instance variable, so the
// next line succeeds.
_stObj = [[Student alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

`@property` automatically implements accessors for the instance variable (and will even create the instance variable if none is specified). So `@property Student *stObj;` is the equivalent och defining and implementing `-(Student *)stObj;` and `-(void)setStObj:(Student*)student;`.

The reason that `stdObj = …` fails is that the default variable name is the property named prefixed with an underscore, so `_stdObj = …` will work.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that a `@property` is not an instance variable; rather, it is the getter/setter for an instance variable.

When used with properties, dot syntax will call the `(void)setObject:(id)object` and `(id)object` methods -- the accessor/mutator for the underlying instance variable. By default, the underlying instance variable is the property name prefixed by an underscore -- this is why you typically don't need `@synthesize stdObj = _stdObj` because that is the default behavior.

With that in mind, if you were to declare a simple iVar, `self.stdObj` would be **illegal** unless you declared a getter/setter for that iVar (or made it a property). `self->stdObj` directly accesses the iVar.