# What is self->property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am familiar in iOS/Objective C. Now I see people using `self->property` in some cases. How does it differ from `self.property`? What is the actual need? I googled, no answer. Curious in it.

Comment: It calls for instance variable.
Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057934/property-vs-instance-variable
for more.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398609/what-does-property-actually-do-behind-the-scene-with-usage-of-self-and-self?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self->property` is the same as `_property`, meaning it accesses the ivar directly.

`self.property` on the other hand calls the setter/getter.